# Xamarin.Forms layout not being loaded after updating

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Edit: Maps was not the problem, it's the forms itself as well.**

In our app we are using `Xamarin.Forms`, and we used to use version `2.3.4.270` which was working fine. However, after updating to the current latest version `2.4.0.18342` and cleaning the solution, we just see a white screen without any exception. Note that not even a part of the actual layout  is rendered at all. No code is changed.

This problem is on an Android device, iOS is working properly.

According to the release notes, there is nothing actually changed a lot in the `Forms` itself:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.4/2.4.0-stable/

Did `Xamarin` change something important in their switch from `2.3` to `2.4` that I am missing out here?

[image]

Comment: make sure are you change version in all project?

Comment: I did @Praktik, the version is the same in all sub-projects.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from the device manually, and then re-installing? Have you put a break point in the constructor of the first page and stepped through it to see if it completes without bombing out?

Comment: It's not bombing out, reinstalling did not work either. It's very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was that we were using `MvvmCross`, this caused several problems in our project so we decided to switch to another framework.

Answer (score 0):

The white screen appears if you did not provide an API key, or if it not valid. Since your iOS project is working fine, my suggestion will be to check your declaration of API key for android.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/#Android

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, the whole layout is not being rendered. My key is correct.